# Specify order for query manually

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in `PostgreSQL` which returns:

```
id      operation   quantity   date
----------------------------------------
1282    WITHDRAW      20    2015-01-01
541     INCOMING      50    2015-01-01
4788    ACCEPT        17    2015-01-01
4789    ACCEPT        20    2015-01-01
.....
```

The query order sort the records by `date`...

However, I want to do a secondary order by `operation`: first `INCOMING`, then `ACCEPT`, then `WITHDRAW`. Order between records of the same operation is not important:

```
541     INCOMING      50    2015-01-01
4788    ACCEPT        17    2015-01-01
4789    ACCEPT        20    2015-01-01
1282    WITHDRAW      20    2015-01-01
```

or

```
541     INCOMING      50    2015-01-01
4789    ACCEPT        20    2015-01-01
4788    ACCEPT        17    2015-01-01
1282    WITHDRAW      20    2015-01-01
```

both ok.

I can not use the `operation` column nor the `id` column because it won't give the desired result...

```
Select ...
from ...
where ...
order by date
```

How can I manually specify the order I want..?

I'm looking for SQL syntax for something like:

```
order by date, (operation order by: INCOMING,ACCEPT,WITHDRAW)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql: Ordering columns to match custom criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713798/postgresql-ordering-columns-to-match-custom-criteria) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an expression for the order by:

```
order by date, 
         case operation 
              when 'INCOMING' then 1
              when 'ACCEPT' then 2
              when 'WITHDRAW' then 3
              else 4 -- this is a fallback, anything else will be sorted at the end
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nicer solution possible since Postgres v9.5.

```
ORDER BY date, 
     array_position(ARRAY['INCOMING', 'ACCEPT', 'WITHDRAW']::varchar[], operation)
```